# Gremlin loop query that returns a list of neighbors' edge counts and ids

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin

I'm trying to write a Gremlin loop that returns something like the following for a vertex:

nodeId:1, edgeCount: 2
nodeId:2, edgeCount: 1
nodeId:3, edgeCount: 3
nodeId:4, edgeCount: 4

In other words, a list of its neighbors' ids along with each neighbor's edge count. The closest I've got is this (for the vertex 'svpol'):

```
g.v('svpol').in.loop(1){it.loops<2}.path{it.id}{g.v(it.id).bothE.count()}
```

which produces the following output:

```
==>[svpol, 2]
==>[svpol, 4]
==>[svpol, 4]
==>[svpol, 6]
```

I have confirmed that the edge counts are correct, but instead of 'svpol' I would want it to produce the id of the neighbor. It needs to be done in a single query if possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly but you write:

> a list of its neighbors' ids along with each neighbor's edge count

Such a list of lists could be obtained with the following simple query using transform (in gremlin 2):

```
l = g.v(id).both.transform{[it.id,it.bothE.count()]}.toList()
```

With the [sample graph](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Property-Graph-Model) for `id=1`, the query will produce:

```
[3, 3]
[2, 1]
[4, 3]
```

I don't see why you want to use `loop`.

Comment: Thank you, I finally got a chance to try it and this gives the right output. Is there a way to sort the output by the edge count?

Comment: Update: I was able to get the sorted output with the following query. g.v('svpol').both.transform{['id':it.id,'ecount':it.bothE.count()]}.toList().sort{it.ecount}

Answer (score 1):

I guess Faber was close and what you're looking for is this:

```
g.v('svpol').both().path() {it} {[it.id, it.bothE().count()]}
```